# Getting rid of "jumps" between facet grids

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am using facet_grid in order to have two labels for the x-axis.

My data looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(22)
df <- c(1:1260)
df <- as_tibble(c(1:1260))
colnames(df)[1] <- "price"
df$price[1] <- 100
for (i in seq(2,1260)){df$price[i]<- df$price[i-1]*0.8 + rlnorm(1, 2, 2)}
df$month <- rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", 
                  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"), 5, each=21)

df$year <- rep(c("Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 4", "Year 5" ), 1, each=252)
```

Using this code by user M-M:

```
df$month <- rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", 
                  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"), 5, each=21)

df$year <- rep(c("Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 4", "Year 5" ), 1, each=252)

#solution:
month_lab <- rep(unique(df$month), length(unique(df$year)))

year_lab <- unique(df$year)

df %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(price = 1) %>% 
  mutate(rnames = rownames(.)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(rnames), y = price, 
             group = year)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Stock Price Chart", y = "Price", x = "date") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 1260, by = 21), 
                     labels = month_lab, expand = c(0,0)) +
  facet_grid(~year, space="free_x", scales="free_x", switch="x") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA,colour="grey50"),
        panel.spacing=unit(0,"cm"))
```

I get almost exactly what I strive for except for the jumps the line makes between years as marked in the picure:

[image: graph]

Is there a way to make the line continious?

Comment: Data generation gives an error. Can you check?

Comment: @RonakShah Changed it. Is it working now?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of this is there is no clean way to do this with facets as `ggplot` will not join the dots. One way to get around this may be to add an extra data point at the end of each `year` group that is equal to the start of each `year` group,

```
df %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(price = 1) %>% 
  split(.$year) %>% 
  lapply(., function(x) bind_rows(x, data.frame(price = NA, month = "Dez", year = unique(x$year)[[1]], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate(price = ifelse(is.na(price), lead(price), price)) %>% 
  mutate(rnames = rownames(.)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(rnames), y = price, 
             group = year)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Stock Price Chart", y = "Price", x = "date") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 1260, by = 21), 
                     labels = month_lab, expand = c(0,0)) +
  facet_grid(~year,space="free_x", scales="free_x", switch="x") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA,colour="grey50"),
        panel.spacing=unit(0,"cm"))
```

Why not just use a normal axis with date labels `Month-Year` like (Jan-2001)? this can be done nicely and prettily using other formats outline [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html), you can rotate the labels for neatness etc.

An alternative would be to create normal Date labels, put it all on the same plot and simply format the dates to be a little more pleasing to the eye in the form of `Mon Year` using `format()`. I find this to be more correct and also simpler to formulate. Using `plotly` you can do this type of thing using groups and subgroups as shown in an example [here](https://plot.ly/r/axes/).

```
# Change to Numeric month
df$month <- rep(c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
                  "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"), 5, each=21)

# Choose real time window in years I chose 2000-2004
df$year <- rep(c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004" ), 1, each=252)
month_lab <- rep(unique(df$month), length(unique(df$year)))

# Construct a date label not just a month 
year_lab <- rep(unique(df$year), 12)
Date_lab <- sort(as.Date(paste0(year_lab, month_lab, "01"), "%Y%m%d"))


df %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(price = 1) %>% 
  mutate(rnames = rownames(.)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(rnames), y = price, 
             group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Stock Price Chart", y = "Price", x = "date") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 1260, by = 21), 
                     labels = format(Date_lab, "%b %Y"), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA,colour="grey50"))
```

In response to Comment, you can do this by taking the sorted `Date_lab` variable and replacing the years withyou required string. A quick way might be with gsub but then you also run into the problem with `Year 0` but that can just be changed however you see fit. Once the labels are sorted in the correct order, you can do whatever you want with them, just remove the call to `format` in the `ggplot` section. ie

```
Date_lab <- 
  gsub("(200)", "Year ", format(sort(as.Date(paste0(year_lab, month_lab, "01"), "%Y%m%d")), "%Y %b"))

df %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(price = 1) %>% 
  mutate(rnames = rownames(.)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(rnames), y = price, 
             group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Stock Price Chart", y = "Price", x = "date") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 1260, by = 21), 
                     labels = Date_lab, expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA,colour="grey50"))
```

Comment: i was afraid of this answer! :( Could you give an example of how it would look like with month-year labels?

Comment: I have added on an alternative to just use a normal axis and make the labels a bit less cluttered. If that is too ugly then `plotly` is a good alternative.

Comment: Is there a way to call the years "year 1", "year 2" etc instead of 2001-2004?